# transform xml with xslt in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xslt

I need to transform a xml string with xslt in Swift.

I am an android developer, so I am trying to find some code to do that in iOS with Swift.

I found this post [Version of XSLT in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462440/version-of-xslt-in-iphone)
and this post [How to process an XMLDocument using EXSLT or XSL 2 in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176864/how-to-process-an-xmldocument-using-exslt-or-xsl-2-in-swift)

The second one seems most recent.
In particular what I need is a function (with 2 parameters, a xml string and a path for saving new file) that transforms xml, saves file on disk and returns the string transformed.

I know it's a bad help request, but I am not able to learn to program in Swift in short times.

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Did you find something ?

Comment: @Fugipe it was long time ago, I do not remember. I solved with ios native code found on the web