# Transforming XML file by using XSLT on iOS(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xml, xslt

New to iOS development.
I'm looking for a way to transform an xml file by using an xslt file for iOS.
I've managed to do that on android, but with no luck on iOS.

Anyone know any solution to that?

I've looked into XMLDocument files, bu they are not available on iOS Swift.
Found some old informations from 2015, 2016 but the solutions are not possible now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176864/how-to-process-an-xmldocument-using-exslt-or-xsl-2-in-swift